# Kernel is able to find a keyfile for one drive, but fails to find keyfiles for other drives

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, luks, initramfs

A friend of mine has a laptop with GNU/Linux. It has a number of disks that are fully encrypted and she carries around unencrypted patitions containing `/boot` and `/boot/efi` on a USB flashdrive. Also on `/boot` are keyfiles to decrypt the disks. She plugs the USB flashdrive into the laptop at boot-time. The keyfiles were added to the luks-headers on the laptop using the `luksAddKey` command of `cryptsetup`. This is a `/etc/crypttab`-file for the operating system:

```
sda1_crypt UUID=c0c16c39-950d-4af6-956c-de187eb077c6 /boot/disk.key luks,discard
mmcblk0_crypt UUID=e4a9c0c2-8ddb-488a-9c5b-cece3ca3d2a2 /boot/disk.key luks
```

You can see for this example, that the keyfile is the same for the two disks. The operating system is Debian-based, so for generating the ramdisk, the `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`-file contains a path to any key files: `/boot/*.key` (such that any keyfiles are included in the ramdisk after running `update-initramfs -u -k all`). The ramdisk was made warning- and error-free using `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

The problem is that during boot, the kernel successfully decrypts sda1, but it provides the following error when trying to decrypt mmcblk0:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: mmcblk0_crypt keyfile '/boot/disk.key' not found
mmcblk0_crypt (starting)...Failed to open key file.
mmcblk0_crypt (failed) ...failed.
```

So it seems it was able to find the keyfile to decrypt sda1 a second earlier, but a second later, it could not find the same keyfile to decrypt mmcblk0. Also, using distinct keyfiles for the two drives was attempted, with the same outcome. This serves as a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

What could be going on? How should we troubleshoot and solve this problem?

---

Edit: We have not modified `grub.cfg` in any way. It has the default settings.

Edit2: For some reason, mmcblk0 is decrypted normally if I move the keyfile for mmcblk0 to `/etc`

Comment: Perhaps you are mounting `sda1_crypt` over `/boot` or `/`?